# Prove there is a point $y$ such that $ g(y)=0 $ where $ g: \bar{D}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $

Tags: general-topology, functions, algebraic-topology

Let $ g: \bar{D}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}   $ be a continuous function on a closed disk satisfying $ g(-x)=-g(x)  $ for any $ x \in  \partial \bar{D}^2$

> Prove that there is a point $ y \in \bar{D}^2 $ such that $ g(y)=0  $

So we need to find a point in the closed disc which maps to a complex number. Would $y=0$ work?

Comment: Algebraic topology is the study of topological spaces by algebraic invariants--- homology groups, cohomology groups, homotopy groups, intersection forms, etc.--- attached to them. Geometric topoology is a bit harder to define, but it deals with manifolds and questions about embeddings, cobordism, surgery theory, etc. Complex analysis deals with holomorphic and meromorphic functions, analytic continuation, etc.: things beyond what you get just be treating $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Why would you think that $y = 0$ works?

Comment: ok, well I can always change them. what tags would you suggest?

Comment: @anomaly I thought it would satisfy $g(0)=-g(0)$ since we are dealing with a disc, but I am not sure

Comment: You only have the relation $g(-x) = -g(x)$ on the boundary, not on the whole disk. In a course about algebraic topology, one natural way to get the result would be to look at the homotopy class of the map $g\lvert_{\partial \overline{D}^2} \colon \partial \overline{D}^2 \to \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ if $g$ doesn't have a zero on the boundary. What would be implied if $g$ has no zero in the disk, and what is implied by the condition $g(-x) = -g(x)$ on the boundary? These two implications are incompatible, hence $g$ must have a zero in the disk.

Comment: @DanielFischer sorry ,thought real valued function